# Is there a way to identify cities in a text without maintaining a prior vocabulary, in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have to identify cities in a document (has only characters), I do not want to maintain an entire vocabulary as it is not a practical solution. I also do not have Azure text analytics api account.

I have already tried using Spacy,  I did ner and identified geolocation and that output is passed to spellchecker() to train the model. But the issue with this is that ner requires sentences and my input has words.

I am relatively new to this field.

Comment: check Standford's NER Tagger

Comment: @halfer I hear what you say , will keep this mind . Thanks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out the [geotext](https://pypi.org/project/geotext/) library.

### Working example with a sentence:

```
text = "The capital of Belarus is Minsk. Minsk is not so far away from Kiev or Moscow. Russians and Belarussians are nice people."

from geotext import GeoText

places = GeoText(text)
print(places.cities)
```

Output:

```
['Minsk', 'Minsk', 'Kiev', 'Moscow']
```

### Working example with list of words:

```
wordList = ['London', 'cricket', 'biryani', 'Vilnius', 'Delhi']

for i in range(len(wordList)):
    places = GeoText(wordList[i])
    if places.cities:
        print(places.cities)
```

Output:

```
['London']
['Vilnius']
['Delhi']
```

---

[geograpy](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy) is another alternative. However, I find geotext light due to lesser number of external dependencies.

Comment: I am still facing difficulty in identifying sub-regions for example : Thane or Gansoli. Can you help me out on this

Comment: Thane or Ghansoli are not cities right? The library I mentioned does checks for cities. For subregions, may be try using geograpy: https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy or for Python 3: https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/

Answer (score 0):

there is a list of [libraries](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-python-libraries-for-extracting-location-from-text) that may help you, 
but from my experience, there is not a perfect library for this. If you know all the cities that may appear in the text, then vocabulary is the best thing